# Gogoc and OpenVPN - can't seem to make them work together

Tags: openvpn, ipv6

I have a problem with my setup and I was hoping you guys could help me figure out what I should do.

I'm currently running a 6LowPAN using RaspberryPi and Arduino nodes. Since I don't have native IPv6 connectivity, I'm relying on gogoc's tunneling. However, I've just recently spotted a problem: my university's firewall blocks all traffic on port 3653 (tcp or udp). Everything was working fine, but now I can not make it work because of this network's restrictions. I've decided to give OpenVPN a try (tunnel all traffic trough my VPS) and although I can connect to gogo6's brokers, I can not connect to the WebSockets I have installed on the RPi. I must work with ipv6 for the whole 6LowPAN architecture to work and so I'm using duia.us to provide dynamic DNS to my global IPv6. When I access the webpage (rpi.duia.us), the Web Sockets do not work because of OpenVPN. I' guessing there is something wrong about OpenVPN's configuration and the VPS firewall rules regarding IPv6 but I can't figure it out.

Client.conf: https://pastee.org/qhf86

Server.conf: https://pastee.org/qt3gh

raspberrypi file (inside ccd folder --client-config-dir):

```
iroute 2001:05c0:1508:8600::/56
iroute 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

iptables.rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Sat Sep 13 11:45:01 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [24:1354]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [777:80300]
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 3603 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3603 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8181 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.88.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 8181 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 500 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 13 11:45:01 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Sat Sep 13 11:45:01 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5983:636086]
:INPUT ACCEPT [4972:525285]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [939:103124]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4215:517772]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5153:620808]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 13 11:45:01 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Sat Sep 13 11:45:01 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [34:1995]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8:403]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8:403]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.88.0/24 -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.88.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.161.49.37
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Sep 13 11:45:01 2014
```

MY VPS has 4 different IPv6 addresses and my gogoc client (RPi) has its own prefix which I've included in the --client-config-dir.

At first I thought I wouldn't need any IPv6 on OpenVPN since I'm using v6udpv4 with gogoc (IPv6 inside IPv4 via udp for nat traversal), but it doesn't seem to work that way. Now I need help with IPv6 support...

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Pedro

Comment: Do you mean gogo6?

Comment: Yeah, gogoc is the client. I am using the broker gogo6 with a registered account, though.